# Function fails to write to integer

Tags: c, binary

I have the following code:

```
int vals = 0b000000000000000000;
void setBit(int num, int x, int n) {
  num ^= (-x ^ num) & (1 << n);
}
int main() {
  setBit(vals, 0, 1);
  printf("%i\n", vals);
}
```

But, the `setBit()` function does not write to `vals`! The `printf()` prints 0, but it should print 1 (`vals` is `0b000000000000000001`). Why?

Comment: You never change values. A copy of vals is given to the function, then you change that.

Comment: `0b000...` is invalid syntax

Comment: because you pass vals by value. every thing in C pass by value.

Comment: The code invokes undefined behaviour for certain shift counts and values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make a copy of `vals` when you pass it in since you don't pass a pointer. Instead of trying to modify the argument, just return the modified value :

```
int vals = 0b000000000000000000;

int setBit(int num, int x, int n) {
  num ^= (-x ^ num) & (1 << n);
  return num;
}

int main() {
  vals = setBit(vals, 0, 1);
  printf("%i\n", vals);
}
```

Try not to unnecessarily modify arguments. It arguably hurts readability. Prefer returning whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

In C, parameters are passed by value. So their value, despite what happens inside the function, does not change after the call.

Just return the changed value.

Or use a pointer:

```
int vals = 0b000000000000000000;
void setBit(int* num, int x, int n) {
  *num ^= (-x ^ *num) & (1 << n);
}
int main() {
  setBit(&vals, 0, 1);
  printf("%i\n", vals);
}
```

Comment: "as in most languages" - questionable and unnecessary statement. Java, Python, etc. tell different.

Comment: @Olaf I agree on "questionable" part, disagree in examples. Java also uses pass-by-value. (When java objects are passed, a reference to that object is actually passed by value). [Post edited btw]

Comment: References are the opposite of pass-by-value, they are no first-class types (they don't have a value of their own). Not sure about simple types/scalars, but IIRC objects are passed by reference in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The formal parameter `num` in `setBit` is a different object in memory than the actual parameter `vals` in `main`; any updates to `num` are not reflected in `vals`.

You have two options here; either do like Carcigenicate suggests and return the new value:

```
int setBit(int num, int x, int n) 
{
  num ^= (-x ^ num) & (1 << n);
  return num;
}
...
vals = setBit( vals, 0, 1 );
```

Or, use a pointer:

```
void setBit( int *num, int x, int y )
{
  *num ^= (-x ^ *num) & (1 << n);
}
...
setBit( &vals, 0, 1 );
```